# Problems with lein installation in a macbook

Tags: macos, clojure, installation, leiningen

I'm trying to install lein in my new macbook (osx 10.8.2) following the tutorial on https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen

When executing the lein script, I'm getting this error:

/bin/lein: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1187cocoasubrtf340: command not found
/bin/lein: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/bin/lein: line 2:`{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}'

The script I'm using is this one 
https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/preview/bin/lein

Comment: What have you done yourself to try and troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: I checked the script text. It is the same as the url. I'm a osx newbie, so, I don't know what I am doing. Help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{rtf1 ...` comes from an rtf document.
I suppose you haven't copy/pasted the script from the web into a document using TextEdit?
That program defaults to rtf, which could cause this problem.

You should try pasting in a 'decent' text editor. Try your IDE, or Vim or nano or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. That is what happened. I used Emacs and problem is solved now.

Comment: Great. So if this answers your question, could you mark it as such? There's a checkmark next to my answer, if you click it my answer will be marked as accepted. Thanks!